# Adding index to Firebase rules

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am querying data from Firebase based on user's current location using GeoFire. I am getting:

> Using an unspecified index. Consider adding ".indexOn": "g" at / to
>   your security rules for better performance

in console. Below is my querying code:

```
            ref = Database.database().reference()
            let geoFire = GeoFire(firebaseRef: ref)

            let center = CLLocation(latitude: (userLocation.coordinate.latitude), longitude: (userLocation.coordinate.longitude))

            let circleQuery = geoFire?.query(at: center, withRadius: 1)

            circleQuery?.observe(.keyEntered, with: { key, location in

                guard let key = key else { return }

                geoFire?.getLocationForKey(key, withCallback: { (location, error) in

                    let myAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    myAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((location?.coordinate.latitude)!, (location?.coordinate.longitude)!);
                    self.currentLocationMapView.addAnnotation(myAnnotation)      
                })


                self.ref.child("services").child(key).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                    let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                    let servicename = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let address = value?["address"] as? String ?? ""

                    self.nameArray.append(servicename)
                    self.addressArray.append(address)


                    if (self.nameArray.count > 0) {
                        self.customTableView.reloadData();     
                    }

                })

            })
```

My Firebase rules tab has following settings.

```
"rules": {
    ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null"
          }
```

No matter where I insert ".indexOn": "g", I got error and unable to save the rules. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc) points you to [examples](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/tree/master/examples/securityRules).

```
"rules": {
  ".read": true,
  ".write": "auth != null",
  ".indexOn": ["g"]
}
```